# Вычисление коэффициентов аффинной трансформации

Tags: гис, алгоритм

Где-нибудь есть готовые формулы? Понятно, что уравнения там тривиальные, но мне некогда их решать, всё-таки 6 неизвестных - слишком много, чтобы не наделать ошибок и потом целый день не вылавливать блох.

Мне нужно получить коэффициенты по трём парам точек.

Comment: По машграфу делали работу: загружается фигура, потом её можно под разными углами и с разных расстояний смотреть, там говорили про аффинные преобразования, скидывать коды или это не то? Там были ещё синусы и косинусы.

Comment: Для аффинных преобразований тригонометрия не требуется, там всё линейно.

Comment: Ну я поэтому и спросил) вот ниже ответ был дан, для него тоже необходимо формулы выписать, у меня они есть. Они нужны для рисования фигур, которые смотрятся под разными углами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поворот вокруг оси Ох на угол alpha

1;         0;           0;

0; cos(alpha); -sin(alpha);

0; sin(alpha); cos(alpha);

Поворот вокруг оси Оy на угол teta

cos(teta); 0; sin(teta);

```
 0;      1;      0;
```

-sin(teta); 0; cos(teta);

Поворот вокруг оси Оz на угол psi

cos(psi); -sin(psi); 0;

sin(psi);  cos(psi); 0;

```
  0;        0;     1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь кратко показан алгоритм: [аффинные преобразования](http://gis-lab.info/qa/affine-math.html). Все сводится к вычислению обратных матриц. Самостоятельно реализовывать обращение матриц смысла нет, лучше взять любой готовый код из сети.

Comment: Это я уже читал. Я бы всё-таки хотел формулы. Программно-то и не надо обращать матрицы, формулы можно вывести, сделав обращение аналитически. Но именно это я делать не хочу, т.к. боюсь наделать ошибок, которые долго вылавливать.